# create Replicaset with separate pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I want to create a ReplicaSet with separate pods.

#### `Pods`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: user-pod
  labels:
    app: user-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: user-container
      image: kia9372/store-user
```

#### `Replicaset`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: user-replicaset
  labels:
    app: user-replicaset
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-pod
```

but when i execute the following command, it throws the foloowing error:

```
kubectl create -f user-replicaset.yml 
 
>error: error validating "user-replicaset.yml": 
error validating data: ValidationError(ReplicaSet.spec.selector): 
unknown field "app" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.LabelSelector; 
if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

**What's the problem? how can I solve this?**

Comment: That error doesn't seem to match the YAML you have: the `selector` field is of type `LabelSelector`, and `app` isn't an immediate child of it.  Can you double-check the indentation of what you have locally?  (It's also really unusual to directly create a ReplicaSet; you'd more commonly create a Deployment, which internally manages ReplicaSets.)

Comment: @DavidMaze yes i know i can create a Development but i need to use the seprate files

Comment: (It looks like you edited the question to add `matchLabels:`; the error you have matches the original question without that field, and [@AydinK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65749041/10008173).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't create replicaset without `spec.template.spec.containers` field. as this one is by default required to create replica-set in k8s. so you must need to add template field . and you can actually do what you want , just use your pod as here in template spec. template is the actual pod spec with which you are going to create your replica-set's pods.

this one is going to do the exact thing you are asking for:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: user-replicaset
  labels:
    app: user-replicaset
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user-container
        image: kia9372/store-user
```

Answer (score 1):

matchlabels is missing. Also your pod definition does not define a matching  label.

Have a look at the docs for a proper setup:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/

Comment: i edit my question but still show me that error

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding that label also in `Replicaset :`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet    
metadata:
  labels:
    app: user-replicaset
    app: user-pod
```

This [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) uses that label in both `labels`